# MySQL datetime default time with interval

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Is it possible to add to a default time with NOW(), 10 minutes?

I've tried something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
);
```

However, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think you can do this.

The [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) states that:

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a
>   TIMESTAMP column

Comment: just for the record, I usually use now() as default in MariaDB, however it just converts it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when table is created

Answer (score 5):

You could however use an insert-trigger to accomplish this. Set the default for the 'date' column to null, and use

```
CREATE TRIGGER settime
BEFORE INSERT on table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.`date` is null THEN
        SET new.`date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It shows me error in line 5:                                       **SET new.`date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);** (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 )

Comment: I tested it on Mysql 5.1 - what version do you have? Also, you need to alter the table to allow for nulls, and set default to null.

Comment: I've already set the default value to NULL and allowed nulls. The version is - 5.5.13.

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 8.0.13, you can now achieve this by wrapping the default expression in parentheses:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datetime_interval_example`
(
  ...
  `later` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE),
  ...
);
```

The [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) posted by @DavidSteele in their answer demonstrates this as well.