# Error on default value with datetime column

Tags: php, mariadb

I'm trying the following query through phpmyadmin to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app`.`token` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  `expiration_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '+ INTERVAL 1 HOUR,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 5
```

If I remove the default value of expiration_date, or change it only to NOW() the query is successful.

Also, the following query is successful too:

```
INSERT INTO `app`.`token` (`token`,`expiration_date`) VALUES ('b1ae528de7ec8355a655926fcb84397f5d21d604e232b6567471c84610a171a8', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

The NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR works with the INSERT statement but not as the default value. 
Why is not working as the default value?
Do I need a trigger for this?

Comment: An AFTER INSERT trigger is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you pala_! You should have made an answer.

Comment: Good thing I didn't, you want a BEFORE INSERT trigger, not an AFTER :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the trigger you'll need:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER expiryDateTrigger BEFORE INSERT on token
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET expiration_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And here's a fiddle showing it in operation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8f53/1

It's necessary to change the delimiter when creating a trigger so you can use the semi-colon inside the trigger definition.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions for default values are not supported in MariaDB or MySQL. From the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/):

> You must provide a constant default value instead. The one exception
>   is that you may use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value for a
>   TIMESTAMP column to use the current timestamp at insertion time.

See also [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html) and [a previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024010/mysql-datetime-default-time-with-interval) relating to the same topic in MySQL.

Comment: MySQL as of version 5.6.5 also supports CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default for DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `DATE_ADD` mysql function

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

So your query would change to this

```
INSERT INTO `app`.`token` (`token`,`expiration_date`) VALUES ('b1ae528de7ec8355a655926fcb84397f5d21d604e232b6567471c84610a171a8', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR));
```

Comment: His query is fine. His question is why the + INTERVAL syntax works for the query, but not for the schema creation.