# How to add days to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Is that possible to set something add 30 days at Default value (have a look at the picture)?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Short answer no. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024010/mysql-datetime-default-time-with-interval

Comment: You could use the trigger solution also mentioned in that link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL datetime default time with interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024010/mysql-datetime-default-time-with-interval)